# Why is my compiler giving me these two errors in Java?

Tags: java

I'm writing a code in Java and I keep getting two errors from the compiler saying "cannot find symbol." Here is my code and the errors.

```
public ComplexNumber(float a, float b){
    a = real;
    b = imaginary;
}
```

Here are the two errors.

```
ComplexNumber.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
    a = real;
        ^
symbol:   variable real
location: class ComplexNumber
ComplexNumber.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
    b = imaginary;
        ^
symbol:   variable imaginary
location: class ComplexNumber
2 errors
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are `real` and `imaginary` defined in your program?

Comment: Because `real` and `imaginary` are not defined in your class, and also I believe you should be assigning your parameter values to some field, rather than over writing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I see two glaring errors, the first of which is what the compiler is telling you, namely that `real` and `imaginary` have not been declared anywhere.  In Java, you cannot use a variable unless you have previously declared it.  You probably want to have a **real** and **imaginary** component of your `ComplexNumber`, so you need to declare member variables for it appropriately.

e.g.

```
public class ComplexNumber {
    float real;
    float imaginary;
    ...
```

The second error is that you are trying to assign the values of `real` and `imaginary` to your parameter variables, instead of the other way around.  When you do this, you are throwing away the data that is being passed in to your method instead of storing it:

```
public ComplexNumber(float a, float b){
    a = real;       // this overwrites the value of a instead of using it
    b = imaginary;  // this overwrites the value of b instead of using it
}
```

Generally, the convention in Java is to try to give your member variables informative names, and then in your constructors, getters and setters, use the same names with a `this.` prefix for the member variables to distinguish them from the parameters.

Most modern IDEs will automatically generate your code for you in this format.

e.g.

```
public class ComplexNumber {
    float real;
    float imaginary;

    public ComplexNumber(float real, float imaginary) {
        this.real = real;
        this.imaginary = imaginary;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the variables `real` and `imaginary`, which do not exist. I think you have a general misconception about parameters. What you want is something like this:

```
public class ComplexNumber
{
    float real;          // Attribute for the real part
    float imaginary;     // Attribute for the imaginary part

    public ComplexNumber(float r, float i) // Constrctor with two parameters
    {
         real = r;       // Write the value of r into real
         imaginary = i;  // Write the value of i into imaginary
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Calling the constructor, setting real to 17 and immaginary to 42
        ComplexNumber c = new ComplexNumber(17, 42);
        System.out.println(c.real); // yielding 17
        System.out.println(c.imaginary); // yielding 42
    }
}
```